# Índices em lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Boa tarde, esta semana meu professor me passou a questão de programar uma agenda telefônica. Fiz com dicionário mas ele me mandou refazer com listas.

> Chegou uma parte em que eu tenho que remover um contato da agenda telefônica e o seu número. Mas não sei como remover o nome que é um índice desconhecido. Se eu conseguir descobrir o índice do nome, é fácil remover o índice do número. Mas como eu descubro o índice do nome?

```py
agenda = []
while True:
    print("=================")
    print("Agenda INTIN")
    print("=================")
    print("Menu de opções:")
    print("1 - Cadastrar novo contato")
    print("2 - Buscar contato")
    print("3 - Alterar contato")
    print("4 - Excluir contato")
    print("5 - Listar todos os contatos")
    print("6 - Sair")
    print("----------------------------")
    opcao = int(input("Digite uma opcao: "))
    if(opcao == 4):
        busca = input("Digite o nome do contato que deseja excluir: ")
        if(busca in lista == True):
            agenda.remove("busca")
            agenda.remove(
            print("Contato excluido com sucesso")
        else:
            print("ERROR")
            print("Contato inexistente")
        print("----------------------------")
```

Comment: Seja bem-vinda, tente usar um `agenda.index(busca)` deve retornar o index e depois é só remover

Comment: o index retorna num print? como ele retorna?? ;-; (desculpa, to no 1° ano de informatica e sou novata)

Comment: Lembre-se de que todos somos estudantes! ILeia isto, irá te ajudar [Usando o método index () da lista do Python em uma lista de tuplas ou objetos?](https://www.it-swarm.net/pt/python/usando-o-metodo-index-da-lista-do-python-em-uma-lista-de-tuplas-ou-objetos/957585152/)

Comment: Obrigada! Foi muito gentil da sua parte ^^